# Skewness of log-normal distribution only depending on variance?

Tags: variance, skewness, lognormal-distribution

Wikipedia says that the skewness of the log-normal distribution only depends on the variance of the underlying normal distribution.

Skewness: [image]

However, from my point of view the skewness increases as the mean of the underlying normal distribution increases (described [here](http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue47/relbasics47.htm)).

Can anyone show which point is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the ambiguity comes from how you define *skewness*.  Wikipedia uses
$$
  \mathrm{E}\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^3, \text{ with } 
  \mu=\mathrm{E}X \text{ and } \sigma^2=\mathrm{E}(X-\mu)^2.
$$
If you compute this for $X\sim \text{log-normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, you arrive at the given formula.  During the calculation, the dependency on $\mu$ is normalized out when you divide by $\sigma^3$.  To check this, write $X = \exp(\mu+\sigma Z)$ for
$Z\sim\text{Normal}(0,1)$ and try calculating the moments.

Alternatively, the third moment, $\mathrm{E}X^3$, and the third central moment, $\mathrm{E}(X-\mathrm{E}X)^3$ certainly do depend on $\mu$.  Your cited web page doesn't define *skewness*, but I assume they are referring to the third central (unnormalized) moment.